# android trust manager vulnerability

Tags: android, encryption, google-play, android-security

I received a very disturbing email from google:

> We reviewed `app name`, with `package name`, and found that your app
> uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users. Apps
> with these vulnerabilities can expose user information or damage a
> user's device, and may be considered to be in violation of our
> Malicious Behavior policy.
>
> Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that
> were detected in your recent submission. Please migrate your apps to
> use the updated software as soon as possible and increment the version
> number of the upgraded APK.
>
> Vulnerability APK Version(s)  Deadline to fix TrustManager You can find
> more information about TrustManager in this Google Help Center
> article.
>
> 486   September 14, 2020 Vulnerability    APK Version(s)  Deadline to fix To
> confirm you've upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of your
> app to the Play Console and check back after five hours. We'll show a
> warning message if the app hasn't been updated correctly.
>
> While these vulnerabilities may not affect every app, it's best to
> stay up to date on all security patches.
>
> If you have technical questions about the vulnerability, you can post
> to Stack Overflow and use the tag "android-security." For
> clarification on steps you need to take to resolve this issue, you can
> contact our developer support team.
>
> Best,
>
> The Google Play Team

The only new thing added on app version 486 is an RSA encryption I added to some data.

This encryption is made in the following way: I manually generated an RSA key pair, stored the private key in my server and deployed the public key together with the apk.

For some requests in the app, I use the public key to encrypt the data before sending it through post request using `URLConnection` on the server side I decrypt it and process, then I send the response back to the user **UNENCRYPTED**.

so take in consideration the following:
0- there are only two requests in the app that use this technic
1- this update was made to ensure all the requests which arrive at the server came from my official app since last week I got 3 DoS attacks
2- those request existed for ages and always used standard android `HTTPSUrlConnection` without any extra encryption... what I made now was add an extra layer of encryption (how could it make the app less secure?)
3- the data transmitted is completely inoffensive

I know what a MITM attack is and I have done it for ages to reverse engineer some apps, I can't make this type of attack against my app without modifying the compiled code

That being said, how can I solve this problem without downgrade the work i took one week to implement?

this is the code:

```
post.put("p", "test");
            post.put("s", Encrypter.encrypt(userid + "|" + did));
            final String data = SimpleJsonDeserializer.getDefaultJson().toJson(post);
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(data);
            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(App.CLOUD_FUNCTIONS_HOST + "warsaw?v=2").openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.addRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
            conn.addRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            conn.addRequestProperty("content-length", data.length() + "");
            conn.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes());
            conn.getOutputStream().flush();
            conn.getOutputStream().close();
```

this is the Encrypter class (which is the new added on `486`)

```
public final class Encrypter {

    private static Cipher cipher;


    public static void initialize(@NonNull final Context c) {
        if (cipher == null) {
            try {
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
                X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode("my public key base64 coded".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kf.generatePublic(spec));
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidKeyException e) {
                App.shouldNeverHappen(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(@NonNull final String s) throws IllegalBlockSizeException {

        if (s.isEmpty() || s.length() > 240)
            throw new IllegalBlockSizeException("Data must not be longer than 245 bytes");


        try {
            return new String(Base64.encode(cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes()), Base64.DEFAULT));
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            App.shouldNeverHappen(e);
            return "";
        }

    }

}
```

The only way to use "inject" a malicious key would modify the compiled code (which is IMPOSSIBLE to prevent) but even doing this the attacker would only be able to **modify the post data signature in the requests SENT**
what would be useless for any sort of phishing attack

I'm 100% sure this kind of warning is flagged by some automatical code inspection (which google spend ZERO work on re-evaluating manually), so since I got this problem, i've deployed several versions of my app just "masking around" the code to try not to be flagged on this automatic code inspection... not successful so far.

Comment: I suggest that you talk this out with the Google Support themselves.

Comment: google doesnt provide support for normal users. only if you spend some millions a year with them you get support

Comment: That code does not seem like what they are complaining about. Are you sure that you are not configuring an `SSLContext` anywhere with a custom `TrustManager`, or perhaps are using a library that is doing that?

Comment: @CommonsWare 100% sure, 'SSLContext' nor 'TrustManager' are no even imported by any classes of my app. all network requests are made either by Firebase, or URLConnection without any customizations

Comment: "no even imported by any classes of my app" -- you might want to use APK Analyzer and check to see if any libraries that you are using are referencing those classes.

Comment: I only import few apis and i could write them here from my mind. they are: firebase (database, analytics, storage, messaging) picasso google billing, retrofit2 and okhttp3

Comment: You know you don't need this if you're communicating over HTTPS right?  Your quick homemade transport layer security implementation won't even begin to stack up to the 20 years of experience SSL and TLS have had.  You might as well remove it - app reviews are generally easier without explicit use of crypto primitives.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark, if you took 5 minutes to read the whole text instead of just the tittle you will notce that i made this because i got some ddos attacks not for "protect" users data

Comment: Well, like it or not, what you've written is transport security.  Transport security does nothing to alleviate DDoS attacks.  I can't see any good reason to keep it.  Just my advice, don't take it so personally.